# query not displaying if another table has null value(sequence contains no elements)

Tags: mysql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  a problem with the following code. It displays details if all tables have at least one value, but nothing if at least one table does not have a value. I get the message

> sequence contains no elements.

My code as follow:

```
public sneakerDetails GetSneakerDetails(int id)
{
    IQueryable<sneakerDetails> query = from sneaks in _context.sneakers
                                       from image in _context.sneakerImages 
                                       from website in _context.sneakerWebsites 
                                       // from website in _context.sneakerWebsites 
                                       where sneaks.sneaker_id == id && image.sneaker_id == website.sneaker_id && sneaks.sneaker_id == website.sneake_id
                                       select new sneakerDetails
                                       {
                                           //sneaker_id = sneaks.sneaker_id,
                                           Colorway = sneaks.Colorway,
                                           Name = sneaks.Name,
                                           description = sneaks.description,
                                           imageAlternative = image.imageAlternative,
                                           release_date = sneaks.release_date,
                                           imageB = image.imageB,
                                           imageF = image.imageF,
                                           imageL = image.imageL,
                                           imageR = image.imageR,
                                           website = website.website,
                                           websiteLogo = website.websiteLogo
                                       };


    return query.ToList().First();
```

I have tried to change the return value to `FirstOrDefault` but when i click a particular sneaker it displays only the title and no data.

Do i need to write an `if` statement for both tables?

Comment: It's the same as inner joins. Why do you do it this way? Can you use navigation properties like `sneaker.sneakerImages`?

Comment: i cannot access the other tables like you said sneaker.sneakerimages as its from another table I have 3 table that are linked together sneaker can have many images and a sneaker can belong to many websites. hope that helps

Comment: The idea of navigation properties is that they connect data from different tables. Usually, if you can join you can also create/use navigation properties. What kind of LINQ is this, or, what kind of class is `_context`?

Comment: i am using the data access object DAO? sorry im really new to mvc

Comment: OK, take some time to get the gist of the data layer you're using. It's probably Entity Framework and `_context` is probably derived from `DbContext`. Or is it linq-to-sql? Only you can tell. And you *should* know before moving on, otherwise you keep running into issues like this, and worse. And it's virtually impossible to get the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
from sneaks in _context.sneakers.DefaultIfEmpty()
from image in _context.sneakerImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
from website in _context.sneakerWebsites.DefaultIfEmpty()
// from website in _context.sneakerWebsites 
where sneaks.sneaker_id == id
    && image.sneaker_id == website.sneaker_id
    && sneaks.sneaker_id == website.sneake_id
select new sneakerDetails
{
    //sneaker_id = sneaks.sneaker_id,
    Colorway = sneaks.Colorway,
    Name = sneaks.Name,
    description = sneaks.description,
    imageAlternative = image.imageAlternative,
    release_date = sneaks.release_date,
    imageB = image.imageB,
    imageF = image.imageF,
    imageL = image.imageL,
    imageR = image.imageR,
    website = website.website,
    websiteLogo = website.websiteLogo
};
```